# How do I to run multiple applications and manage them over SSH on one Ubuntu Server?

Tags: server, minecraft, nas

I would like to run a Spigot Minecraft server and a Samba NAS server on the same box and access them both at the same time. How do I do this?

Comment: SSH will give you a terminal connection to the server, then you can run whatever commands you need from that point.  The basic command is ssh ipaddress, you will be prompted for username ans passsword, and you are in.  On the serrver make sure you have open ssh installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could connect with server with ssh clients, but once disconnected, it's hard to get your console back.

There is a program to manage console named **screen**.

```
sudo apt-get install screen
```

Create a new session by

```
screen -S seesion_name
```

Then execute your command and press Ctrl + A then D to unbind the session. The commands will still run. You can get back to your session by typing

```
screen -r seesion_name
```